# saving data from textview

Tags: android, android-ndk

I created a DB in my application. I have one TextView in my application, I need to save the data whatever in textview. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared Preferences will be helpful to you to store data. Here is the docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

And the text from textview can be obtained using

```
String textToStore = textview.getText().toString;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your database adapter class create a method to insert a single value in your database like

```
public void insert(String data)
    {
        ContentValues in=new ContentValues();
        in.put("data", data);

        db.insert(table_name, null, in);
    }
```

Create a object of your adapter class and then call the method insert with the value of your edit text.

```
public void insert(Object data)
    {
        ContentValues in=new ContentValues();
        //in.put("data", (String) data);
        in.putAll((ContentValues) data);

        db.insert(table_name, null, in);
    }
```

Here you can can pass any object to insert in the database.

Answer (score 0):

get data from textview:

```
String var = yourtextview.getText().toString();
```

save this variable as per your need..